# I cant figure out how to process this nested object into a table in React. Any help would be appreaciated

Tags: reactjs

I want the date and the rates that belongs to that date into a table. The original dataset is the same, only that there are much more dates containing rates, so i cant just access it using dot notation.

```
        const json = [
            {
                _id: '5f746f892103e3371429dcd0',
                date: '2020-05-05T00:00:00.000Z',
                rates: {
                    CAD: 1.5201,
                    HKD: 8.4057,
                    ISK: 159.3,
                    PHP: 54.863,
                    DKK: 7.4612,
                    HUF: 350.27,
                    CZK: 26.978,
                    AUD: 1.6825,

                },
                __v: 0,
            },
            {
                _id: '5f746f892103e3371429dd6f',
                date: '2020-05-04T00:00:00.000Z',
                rates: {
                    CAD: 1.539,
                    HKD: 8.4838,
                    ISK: 159.5,
                    PHP: 55.379,
                    DKK: 7.4622,
                    HUF: 353.27,
                    CZK: 27.119,
                },
                __v: 0,
            },
        ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to solve the problem

This is a little different but it has similar logic and map functions

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {

  const json = [
    {
      _id: '5f746f892103e3371429dcd0',
      date: '2020-05-05T00:00:00.000Z',
      rates: {
        CAD: 1.5201,
        HKD: 8.4057,
        ISK: 159.3,
        PHP: 54.863,
        DKK: 7.4612,
        HUF: 350.27,
        CZK: 26.978,
        AUD: 1.6825,

      },
      __v: 0,
    },
    {
      _id: '5f746f892103e3371429dd6f',
      date: '2020-05-04T00:00:00.000Z',
      rates: {
        CAD: 1.539,
        HKD: 8.4838,
        ISK: 159.5,
        PHP: 55.379,
        DKK: 7.4622,
        HUF: 353.27,
        CZK: 27.119,
      },
      __v: 0,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {json.map(obj => (
        <div key={obj._id} >
          {/* {console.log(Object.keys(obj.rates))} */}
          {console.log(`Rates for object ${obj._id}`)}
          {obj.date} -
          {Object.keys(obj.rates).map(rate => (
            <div key={rate} >
              {console.log(`Rate is ${rate} and value is ${obj.rates[rate]}`)}
              {rate} : {obj.rates[rate]},
            </div>
          ))}
          {console.log("\n")}
          <br />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the exact answer (I think)

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {

  const json = [
    {
      _id: '5f746f892103e3371429dcd0',
      date: '2020-05-05T00:00:00.000Z',
      rates: {
        CAD: 1.5201,
        HKD: 8.4057,
        ISK: 159.3,
        PHP: 54.863,
        DKK: 7.4612,
        HUF: 350.27,
        CZK: 26.978,
        AUD: 1.6825,

      },
      __v: 0,
    },
    {
      _id: '5f746f892103e3371429dd6f',
      date: '2020-05-04T00:00:00.000Z',
      rates: {
        CAD: 1.539,
        HKD: 8.4838,
        ISK: 159.5,
        PHP: 55.379,
        DKK: 7.4622,
        HUF: 353.27,
        CZK: 27.119,
      },
      __v: 0,
    },
  ];

  let allRates = []

  json.map(obj => {
    Object.keys(obj.rates).map(rate => {
      allRates.push(rate)
    })
  })

  allRates = [...new Set(allRates)]
  console.log(allRates)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Date
          </th>
          {allRates.map(rate => (
            <th>
              {rate}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
        {json.map(obj => (
          <tr>
            <td>{obj.date}</td>
            {allRates.map(rate => (
              <td>{obj.rates[rate]}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Id also like to say that I think this is the answer that you are expecting. I am not sure so if I have not answered the question comment or reply.

Also, you had told to put it in tables

I did the most basic way of tables

If you wanted something else please reply or comment

[Check this out (Its useful)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

I tried my best

I hope it answers your question